# godep save never works

Tags: heroku, go, godeps

When trying to run `godep save`, I'm always getting the following error:

```
godep: [WARNING]: godep should only be used inside a valid go package directory and
godep: [WARNING]: may not function correctly. You are probably outside of your $GOPATH.
godep: [WARNING]:   Current Directory: /Users/username/Development/my-server
godep: [WARNING]:   $GOPATH: /Users/username/Development/my-server
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that you run this command from a repo that is also defined in your `$GOPATH`.

So it would need to be: `/Users/username/gosource/src/github/foo/my-server/`

This means that not only are all your packages located in your `$GOPATH` but additionally your own repo is located in your `$GOPATH`. At this point everything should work as expected.

If you don't have a `$GOPATH` environment variable defined you need to make sure it is set pre Go1.8.

Try this: `echo $GOPATH` at the command prompt to see if it's defined.

If not, you'll want to choose a location and set it with: `export GOPATH=/your/final/location`.

More details can be [found here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH).

Comment: After changing my GOPATH to `/Users/username/gosource/src/github/foo/my-server/`, I'm still getting `godep should only be used inside a valid go package directory and
godep: [WARNING]: may not function correctly. You are probably outside of your $GOPATH.`